# proof by induction that a phrase belongs to the real numbers group

Tags: induction

Let it be $a \neq 0,a \in \mathbb{R}  $
such that
$a+(1/a) \in \mathbb{Z} $.
prove by induction that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}: a^n +(1/a^n)\in  \mathbb{Z}  $

i tried simplifying the phrase but couldn't use the given claim to prove something

Comment: Do you mean "such that $a+(\frac{1}{a}) \in \Bbb Z$"? If not, the claim (with $\Bbb R$ instead of $\Bbb Z$) is false. Take $n=1$ and $a=\frac{1}{2}$, for example.

Comment: Hint: $$a^{n+1}+\frac{1}{a^{n+1}} = \left(a^n+\frac{1}{a^n}\right)\left(a+\frac{1}{a}\right) - \left(a^{n-1}+\frac{1}{a^{n-1}}\right).$$

Comment: yes i ment Z, thanks so much!
since all of the three phrases in Z that the result is also in Z

Comment: While not a proof by induction, another way to prove this is via the fundamental theorem of symmetric polynomials. Since $a + \frac{1}{a}$ is an integer and $a \times \frac{1}{a}=1$ is an integer, any symmetric polynomial in terms of $a$ and $\frac{1}{a}$ must be an integer

Comment: @roro could you please elaborate how did you come up with simplification? I want to be able to do this alone next time i see this kind of questions

Comment: @gaas I wasn't the one to come up with the simplification. It is explained in Feripinho answer thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a\in\mathbb{R}^*$, such that $a + \dfrac{1}{a}\in\mathbb{Z}$. If $n\in\mathbb{N}$, so $a^n + \dfrac{1}{a^n}\in\mathbb{Z}$.

1. If $n = 1$, then $a^1 + \dfrac{1}{a^1} = a + \dfrac{1}{a} \in\mathbb{Z}$;
2. Suppose it also works until $n = p$: $a^p + \dfrac{1}{a^p}\in\mathbb{Z}$, that is; then
3. We show it also works for $n = p + 1$. Indeed, we multiply the expressions for $n = 1$ and for $n = p$. Since they're both integers, their product is also an integer: $\left(a + \dfrac{1}{a}\right)\left(a^p + \dfrac{1}{a^p}\right) = a^{p+1} + \dfrac{1}{a^{p+1}} + a^{p-1} + \dfrac{1}{a^{p-1}}\in\mathbb{Z}$. By step 2, $a^{p-1} + \dfrac{1}{a^{p-1}}\in\mathbb{Z}$ (since $p - 1 < p$ and it works until $p$). Therefore, we subtract from step 3's expression this last one, getting also an integer, since the subtraction of two integers is also an integer. Hence, $a^{p+1} + \dfrac{1}{a^{p+1}}\in\mathbb{Z}$.

$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\square$

Comment: could you please elaborate how did you come up with simplification? I want to be able to do this alone next time i see this kind of questions? how did you know that in order to solve it we need to multiply the expression of n=1 and the expression n=p??

Comment: That's actually a great question. There's no reason why. I knew I had to reach $a^{p+1} + \dfrac{1}{a^{p+1}}$ somehow, so it sounded reasonable to multiply that expressions. It was basically faith.